# EF Core Environment Selection

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019

We have recently started writing applications in .net core using EF Core in a code first model. Previously we would change the connection string in the web.config to point to the database that we wanted to update and then run `Update-Database -Verbose`, which worked well.

Now to select the environment so that the correct connection string is used we have to run `$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"` and then run `Update-Database -Verbose`. This is where my problem comes in, I can run the command to set the environment to development, but it will still point to my test environment, I can then rerun the exact commands again and it will then point to my development environment.

Is this a known issue, or am I interacting with EF Core incorrectly? I don't want to get to the point that we have this app in production and accidentally updating the production db when attempting to update my dev db.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#update-database

Update-Database -Connection "my-connection-string"

Answer (score 0):

In an ASP .NET Core web app you could set up ConfigureServices in Startup.cs like so to connect to the appropriate DB depending on the current environment:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseThisDb(MyDevDbConnectionString)
        );
        }
        else
        {
            // For production.
            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseThisDb(MyProdDbConnectionString)
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my problem is that the environment is not being set when I make the call. Once it is set, the code works correctly.